# Does ammonolysis of primary and secondary alkyl halides proceed through SN2 mechanism?

Tags: organic-chemistry, halides, nucleophilic-substitution, amines

We know that the first the ammonia acting as nucleophile attack the alkyl halide forming the substituted ammonium salt, but my question is why cannot it proceed through a typical $S_\text N2$ type, mechanism for  secondary or primary alkyl halide , as ammonia is  good nucleophile, so there will be a formation $\ce{R-NH3^+}$ (halogen being a good leaving group will easily leave), then nitrogen will take the electrons from hydrogen as result of which we obtain $\ce{R-NH2}$, why do we get substituted ammonium salt first, then we have to treat it with a strong base to get amine?

Comment: Using degree convention is outdated. It's better to use primary, secondary convention.

Comment: Base is required exactly for the last step. Amine is a base so you need a stronger base to deprotonate it.